# Timing performance of multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, timer

I wrote a small program to check on the performance of threading which I found a couple of questions from the result i obtained

(cpu of my laptop is i5 3220M)

1) The time required pumped up for 2 thread every time I ran the program. Is it because the omp timer I use or I have some logical error in the program?

2) Also will it be better if I use cpu cycle to measure the performance instead?

3) The time continue to decrease as the number of thread increase. I know my program is simple enough so probably requires no context switch but where does the extra performance come? Coz the cpu adj itself to the turbo freq? (Normal 2.6MHz, turbo 3.3MHz according to intel website)

Thanks!

**Output**
    Adding 1 for 1000 million times

```
Average Time Elapsed for 1 threads = 3.11565(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 2 threads = 4.54309(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 4 threads = 2.19321(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 8 threads = 2.48927(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 16 threads = 1.84427(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 32 threads = 1.30958(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 64 threads = 1.08472(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 128 threads = 0.996898(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 256 threads = 1.01366(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 512 threads = 0.951436(Check = 5000000000)
Average Time Elapsed for 1024 threads = 0.973331(Check = 4999997440)
```

**Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>    // for_each
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>        // omp_get_wtime

class Adder{
public:
    long sum;
    Adder(){};
    void operator()(long endVal_i){
        sum = 0;
        for (long i = 1; i<= endVal_i; i++)
            sum++;
    };
};
int main()
{
    long totalCount = 1000000000;
    int maxThread = 1025;
    int numSample = 5;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    Adder adderArray[maxThread];

    std::cout << "Adding 1 for " << totalCount/1000000 << " million times\n\n";

    for (int numThread = 1; numThread <=maxThread; numThread=numThread*2){

        double avgTime=0;
        long check = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i<=numSample; i++){
            double startTime = omp_get_wtime();

            long loop = totalCount/numThread;
            for (int i = 0; i<numThread;i++)
                threads.push_back(std::thread(std::ref(adderArray[i]), loop));

            std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

            double endTime = omp_get_wtime();

            for (int i = 0; i<numThread;i++)
                check += adderArray[i].sum;

            threads.erase(threads.begin(), threads.end());

            avgTime += endTime - startTime;

        }

        std::cout << "Average Time Elapsed for "  << numThread<< " threads = " << avgTime/numSample << "(Check = "<<check<<")\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you appear to be using C++11 you might want to look at std::chrono instead of omp_get_wtime. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/

Comment: I'd also suggest that you crank the number of iterations up by a factor of 10-100, and do the timing once either side of the numSample loop.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to test here, what facet of multithreading. You might need to explain. Also `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) ++sum;` is not really a heavy workload; probably two registers and a single memory location which you always increment. What optimizations did you use? Did you look at the assembly?

Comment: I am just a beginner on threading so the intention is to how the performance is going to be different if I increase the number of thread. May be I should try on some more heavy loaded task?

Btw, no much diff as I can see by changing to chrono or increase the number of iteration. Time Elapse still peak at 2 threads

50bil time
Thread    Time(s)
1         100
2         150
4         148
8         99
16        90
32        62